# ~t returning blank instead of time

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to get the name and time of the oldest file in a folder (By modification date).

I can get the name without any problem using this code

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d %currentfolder% ^| grep -v / ') do (SET FILEINFO=%%x )
```

From my understanding swapping the %%x for %%~tx should return the modified time instead of the filename. But I get a blank instead.

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d %currentfolder% ^| grep -v / ') do (SET FILEINFO=%%~tx )
```

The following code returns the time of a file in the folder but not the oldest one.

```
for %%a in (%currentfolder%\*) do (set LAST_TIME=%%~ta)
```

I tried to combine the first and last code to get the time of the oldest file but it also returns a blank.

```
    for %%b in (%currentfolder%\%FILEINFO%) do (set MAXDATE=%%~tb)
```

What is the error here ? How can I solve this ?

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: The problem is most probably that `dir /B` returns only names of files present in the given directory and the current working directory (of `for /F`) is something else. Try to put `pushd "%currentfolder%"` before the `for /F` loop, then remove the `%currentfolder%` part from the `dir` command line, then put `popd` after the `for /F` loop...

Comment: Do you want to see the filename of the oldest file, or the oldest filedate?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I want to see both but the filename is working. The filedate appears blank.

Comment: Did you look at my answer below?

Comment: @aschipfl it is working thank you. Do you have a link or something that explains this behaviour ? I'm not sure I understand what the problem was.

Comment: I'm going to provide an answer... What's the purpose of `grep` herein?

Comment: I'm not sure, I modified a code I was given. It looks like it is used to only list files and no folders but I guess there are better ways to do it ?

Comment: Well it looks like a-d does the same so I think it can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that your current working directory referred to by `for /F` is not the same as the directory you are searching files in by `dir`.

This can be fixed like this (omitting `grep` as I do not understand its purpose here):

```cmd
rem // Temporarily change to the directory containing the files of interest:
pushd "%currentfolder%"
rem /* The current working directory is now the target directory;
rem    thus both `dir` and `for /F` work in the same directory: */
for /F "delims=" %%x in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:-D') do (set "FILEINFO=%%~tx")
rem // Restore the former working directory:
popd
rem // Just output the gathered information:
echo/%FILEINFO%
```

Alternatively, the `pushd` command line could be replaced by `cd /D "%currentfolder%"` when `popd` is removed, given that you do not need the original working directory to be restored.

---

To understand what was going on in your original code, let us assume:

- the current working directory is `C:\TEST`;
- the content of variable `currentfolder` is `D:\DATA`;
- the directory `C:\TEST` contains nothing but the batch file;
- the directory `D:\DATA` contains a file called `some.txt`;

The command line `dir /b /o-d /a-d %currentfolder%` returns only pure file names (due to its option `/B`), so based on the predefined sample data, the output would be:

> ```cmd
> some.txt
> ```

Now this text is captured by the `for /F` loop. Now the last modification date/time is queried by `%%~tx`, which of course requires access to the file system. Remember that the current working directory is `C:\TEST`, so the `for /F` loop tries to gather the information from the following file:

> ```cmd
> C:\TEST\some.txt
> ```

Since such a file does not exist, the output is blank.

To prove that, simply place a new file `some.txt` into the directory `C:\TEST`, then you would receive the last modification date/time of that file.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

```
@echo off
set "currentfolder=D:\some directory\"
pushd "%directory%"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /od') do (
    set "file=%%i"
    set "moddate=%%~ti"
    goto :done
)
popd
:done
echo %file% %moddate%
```

So we sort by date (oldest first) then set the first filename as `%file%` and it's date to `%moddate%` then we exit the loop so it does not do the same for the other files in the folder.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but unfortunately it has the same problem as my solution, the date appears blank. aschipfl comment under my main post explains why.

Comment: I don't understand? Are you saying that when you place this script into the directory it does not display the date? That is not possible, it works 100%. Or are you refering to going into another folder? If that is the case, I will update.

Comment: I was referring going into another folder. Your current solution works, thank you.